# PHP MyAdmin: Adding Date and Time

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a form with a few fields, mostly text, but also have a Date and a Time field. Im not quiet sure on how to save these to the database table tho. In PHPMyAdmin, I have set the "eventdate" field to DATE type, and "time" field to "TIME" type.

In my JS file, i have:

```
// When "Save Event" is clicked
    form.submit({point: point}, function (event) {
        // Stops page from refreshing
        event.preventDefault();

        // Form validation
        if( !$("input[name=name]", this).val() ) {
          alert('You forgot to enter a name!');
          return false;
     }
        if( !$("textarea[name=description]", this).val() ) {
          alert('You forgot to enter a description!');
          return false;
     }

        // Send elements to 'data' object.
        var data = {
            name: $("input[name=name]", this).val(),
            description: $("textarea[name=description]", this).val(),
            category: $("select[name=type]",this).val(),
            eventdate: $("input[name=date]", this).val(),
            time: $("input[name=time]", this).val(),
            lat: event.data.point.overlay.getPosition().lat(),
            lon: event.data.point.overlay.getPosition().lng()
        };
        trace(data)

        // Sends data to PHP script to database
        $.post("add_event_data.php", data, tidy_maps.saveStopResponse, "json");
```

And the corresponding PHP is:

```
// Insert into DB table "Events"
$statement->prepare("INSERT INTO events (lat, lon, name, description, category, eventdate, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// Add values from the url and add to DB
$statement->bind_param("ddsssss", $_POST['lat'], $_POST['lon'],     $_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['eventdate'], $_POST['time']);
$status = $statement->execute();
```

Its clearly not sending the data to the DB and it must be due to Date and Time, because it was working with another DB Table before i added these in.

Comment: are date and time in the correct format for mysql?

Comment: I'm not really sure, how would I check that?